# No longer able to mount NAS using CIFS

Tags: linux, mount, cifs, nas

I am following notes made previously on mounting my NAS on my Debian system:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=***,password=***,vers=1.0 //NAS_IP_ADDRESS/NAS_DIR /mnt/NAS
```

This is generating the below error:

```
mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I remember when I had first mounted my NAS adding vers=1.0 was necessary for it to work. If I now change the version from 1 to 2 the NAS is mounted.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=***,password=***,vers=2.0 //NAS_IP_ADDRESS/NAS_DIR /mnt/NAS
```

However on adding the below line to /etc/fstab and restarting the machine the NAS is no longer mounted:

```
//NAS_IP_ADDRESS/NAS_DIR /mnt/NAS cifs user=***,password=***,vers=2.0,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

This used to work without fail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no need to reboot. Just try "mount /mnt/NAS" and you may get additional info as to why it is not working.

Comment: It did provide more info and I learned I needed to drop the ",sec=ntlm". Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropped the ",sec=ntlm" from fstab and it works.